# Are Pokémon as intelligent as humans?

Tags: pokemon

Although Pokémon are depicted as real-world animals with huge diversity, I get confused sometimes when I see their intelligence level.

- Pokémon understand and obey their masters' commands precisely all the time (with the exception of a few like Victreebel). It doesn't look like a pet following its master's command.
- Meowth of Team Rocket actually talks in English (originally in Japanese).

What can I infer about Pokémon's intelligence level from this?

Comment: From another stack; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/can-pokemon-aside-from-meowth-learn-how-to-talk

Comment: Does this count as POB?

Comment: It depends. There are a few (Alakazam, Metagross) that are described as being many times *more* intelligent than humans.

Comment: "As intelligent as humans" - which humans, intelligent in which way?  There's a number of different types of intelligence, ranging from social intelligence to emotional to mathematical.  Many different animals are as intelligent or more intelligent than humans in differing areas.  Also, there's a wide variety of intelligence levels in the differing areas in individual humans.

Comment: @Jeff Traditional IQ test result. I know, it is getting obsolete day by day, but it can work here for now.

Comment: Alakazam has an IQ of 5000, and Slowpoke takes a day to notice when it's tail has been bitten. So it varies.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Pokemon are enslaved.

Comment: @Adamant according to what metric? i've never seen an IQ test where the max possible score is anywhere near 5000

Comment: @Hans - Alakazam has.

Comment: I personally have friends who are able to speak and maintain conversation, but which I have seen failing intelligence tests which crows and mice usually pass. Nothing unusual about pokémon appearing to be smart. I'm actually amazed that with such agile hands, they don't control society.

Comment: The MewTwo was specifically designed to be more intelligent that *anything* out there.